# Browsersync randomly crashes/freezes in Webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, browser-sync

I'm currently facing a weird problem within my Webpack 4 setup. When I refresh a page multiple times Browsersync stops working or just freezes and keeps loading an empty page.. and i have to reopen the same localhost:3000 in another tab to make it work again. This is killing my development time.

```
    new BrowserSync({
        // browse to http://localhost:3000/ during development,
        // ./public directory is being served
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        watch: true,
        server: { baseDir: paths.output.base() }
    }),
```

I am using Chrome as my default browser.

Does anyone have a clue what this can be? or how I can debug this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: P.S. This only happens in Chrome Dev tools "responsive" tab.

Comment: I have the same problem with just chrome dev tools open... annoying